# How to configure Nginx for Asp.Net web app access through registered Domain

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-core, nginx

i'm looking for some help on setting up nginx properly so i can access my asp.net web app through my domain. I reviewed several discussions however nothing seemed to help.

Below is my current setup:

1. Nginx installed and configured (will post my config file below)
2. GoDaddy domain DNS configured for DigitalOcean
3. .net app located in /var/www/publish directory.
4. When navigating to www.jeansmax.com (temporary domain) - it shows the default nginx page.
5. ..nginx/sites-available is linked in sites-enabled
6. .net app runs if I run it locally localhost:5000
7. Also my app startup.cs has the UseForwardedHeaders code below as well.
8. Not sure what the issue is...any help is appreciated

nginx config

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   jeansmax.com *.jeansmax.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server deferred;
    return   444;
}
```

UseForwardedHeaders code

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Hi @goodfella looking at the provided c# you are requesting that the application should only use https "app.UseHttpsRedirection();" but your nginx config only references http settings

Comment: hmm...I was following Microsofts tutorial on the nginx setup include the UseHttpsRedirection. Are you saying i need to change my proxy_pass?

Comment: 1.What is the result when you use the command line: `nginx -t`? 2.Did you use `nginx -s reload` after modifying your configuration? 3.If these command lines do not work,could you share your nginx log?

Comment: I just resolved it by updating my DNS to include AAAA for Ipv6 but most importantly I was missing the plugin Lets Encrypt for Nginx and HTTPS in my config. After updating everything and running certbot, I was able to get a valid certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue after updating the following below:

1. Configured DNS for AAAA - IPv6
2. Updated my nginx config file for HTTPS instead of HTTP proxy
3. Installed Lets Encrypt plugin for Nginx
4. Ran certbot again and received a successful certificate.
5. Restarted my application service
6. Restarted my nginx service
7. my domain fired up and working now.